# Programmatic generation of Box.com authorization code

Tags: box-api

Does anyone know why Box.com make it so hard to generate an authorization code programmatically? I wrote some code to do this through screen-scraping, and then recently this broke because (as far as I can tell) one HTTP request parameter changed from [root_readwrite] to root_readwrite. I was able to fix it reasonably quickly (thank you Fiddler), but why make developers go to this trouble?

Judging by the number of questions on this topic, many developers need to do this, presumably for good reason, and I don't think it can be prevented, so why not just embrace it?

Thanks for listening, Martin

Answer (score 0):

The issue with doing OAuth programmatically is that it would effectively defeat the point of OAuth. Users are supposed to be presented with the Box login page so that they never have to give their username and password directly to your app. This allows users to see what permissions your app has over their account (the scope) and also allows them to revoke your app at any time.

Doing login programmatically means that at some point your app knows the user's password. This requires that the user trusts you to not do anything malicious, which usually isn't feasible unless you're a well-trusted name. The user also has to trust that you handle their credentials correctly and won't use them in an insecure way.

Box wants to encourage developers to do authentication the correct and secure way, and therefore isn't likely to support doing OAuth programmatically. You should really try to perform login the supported way by going through the Box login page.

Comment: Hi - in my case, I am not providing my app with the username and password of the user, all I want to do is to pass the app is an authorization code so that it can generate an access key (and refresh key). I know the client id, so I can programmatically generate an authorization code through emulating the sequence of browser requests to access the oath2 URL, log in, and grant the app access to the user, but it is somewhat brittle.

Comment: Just to add: the reason why I need to do this is to automate the testing I do. My test tool has to first get an authorization code to get going, and this is one of the steps I'd like to automate. I believe that I'm doing things the right oauth2 way by passing my application only the authorization code.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. Even if you have an authorization token, it's only supposed to live for 30 seconds. You'd have to go through the entire login flow again anyway once the auth token expires. Unfortunately, there really isn't a good way of automating this for testing other than what you're already doing.

Comment: Hi, so back to my original question: if we're agreed that what I (and I believe many other people) need to do does not represent a security issue, then it would be a tremendous help if it could be supported. Is there any possibility of putting this on the Box API roadmap?